# Routing Error | No route matches [POST] "/subscriptions/create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm working on an application that contains form used to create a new nominee ( store it in the database)
I get the problem with this instruction of the form:

```
<%= form_for :subscription, :url => {:controller => "subscriptions", :action => "create"} do |f| %>
```

this is the error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/subscriptions/create"
```

rake routes

```
  Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
          subscriptions_create GET        /subscriptions/create(.:format)           subscriptions#create
           subscriptions_index GET        /subscriptions/index(.:format)            subscriptions#index
                articles_index GET        /articles/index(.:format)                 articles#index
        new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                    active_admin/devise/sessions#new
            admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                    active_admin/devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                   active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)             active_admin/devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)            active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                               PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                               PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                    admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                          admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format) admin/admin_users#batch_action
             admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)              admin/admin_users#index
                               POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)              admin/admin_users#create
          new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)          admin/admin_users#new
         edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/admin_users#edit
              admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#show
                               PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#update
                               PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#update
                               DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#destroy
   batch_action_admin_contacts POST       /admin/contacts/batch_action(.:format)    admin/contacts#batch_action
                admin_contacts GET        /admin/contacts(.:format)                 admin/contacts#index
   POST       /admin/contacts(.:format)                 admin/contacts#create
             new_admin_contact GET        /admin/contacts/new(.:format)             admin/contacts#new
            edit_admin_contact GET        /admin/contacts/:id/edit(.:format)        admin/contacts#edit
                 admin_contact GET        /admin/contacts/:id(.:format)             admin/contacts#show
                               PATCH      /admin/contacts/:id(.:format)             admin/contacts#update
                               PUT        /admin/contacts/:id(.:format)             admin/contacts#update
                               DELETE     /admin/contacts/:id(.:format)             admin/contacts#destroy
               admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                admin/dashboard#index
                admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)                 admin/comments#index
                               POST       /admin/comments(.:format)                 admin/comments#create
                 admin_comment GET        /admin/comments/:id(.:format)             admin/comments#show
                      articles GET        /articles(.:format)                       articles#index
                               POST       /articles(.:format)                       articles#create
                   new_article GET        /articles/new(.:format)                   articles#new
                  edit_article GET        /articles/:id/edit(.:format)              articles#edit
                       article GET        /articles/:id(.:format)                   articles#show
                               PATCH      /articles/:id(.:format)                   articles#update
                               PUT        /articles/:id(.:format)                   articles#update
                               DELETE     /articles/:id(.:format)                   articles#destroy
               welcome_sponsor GET        /welcome/sponsor(.:format)                welcome#sponsor
                 welcome_photo GET        /welcome/photo(.:format)                  welcome#photo
                 welcome_index GET        /welcome/index(.:format)                  welcome#index
                          root GET        /                                         welcome#index
```

best regard

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the lines below:

```
Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
subscriptions_create GET        /subscriptions/create(.:format)           subscriptions#create
```

you have got a route for subscriptions_create but it needs to be POST instead of GET. Simply update this route in your routes.rb file in your config folder to be a POST instead of a GET.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this line
`subscriptions_create GET /subscriptions/create(.:format)`, that route is only available when using `GET` HTTP method.

You need to change your routes.rb file for subscriptions to accept POST instead of GET. The easiest way would be to add `resources :subscriptions`, which will add all standard CRUD routes for resource.

Comment: thak you for this answer, i already add the :ressource:subscriptions

Comment: I dont really understand how to put the url i tried to check documentation for that i read and reread invain maybe because of stuck and being disable to think at this moment

Comment: Please add your config/routes.rb file.